# Authentication Agent Protocols for SSH

Tags: ssh

Is the protocol described at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-agent-02 actually implemented by any ssh agent? pageant [implements a different protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12452933/569976) as does [OpenSSH's ssh-agent](http://api.libssh.org/rfc/PROTOCOL.agent).

Comment: The IETF link you posted is only a draft, not an official RFC.  I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't implemented by anyone yet.

Comment: That's what it's seeming like. But then again SFTP was never made into a formal RFC either (only ever existed as a draft) and it's quite widely implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the enterprise grade key agents from ssh.com utilise these scheme's inside there environments. (I have not been able to found a "proof" of that, just a educated guess based on the authors of the IFC Draft and the "hints" on the ssh.com product specs.)

the features the list seem to be able to do the things listed in the draft.